# Do Views need to be deallocated in D3D12? (Will they cause a leak if you don't?)

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management, directx-12

I am learning DirectX12 from this guide [here](https://www.3dgep.com/learning-directx-12-2/#Tutorial2ResizeDepthBuffer) and one thing that has me confused is when they are resizing the depth buffer. This is how they do it below:

```cpp
void Tutorial2::ResizeDepthBuffer(int width, int height)
{
    if (m_ContentLoaded)
    {
        // Flush any GPU commands that might be referencing the depth buffer.
        Application::Get().Flush(); //this here wait for any pending command lists to finish execution on the command queue

        width = std::max(1, width);
        height = std::max(1, height);

        auto device = Application::Get().GetDevice();

        // Resize screen dependent resources.
        // Create a depth buffer.
        D3D12_CLEAR_VALUE optimizedClearValue = {};
        optimizedClearValue.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
        optimizedClearValue.DepthStencil = { 1.0f, 0 };


        ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateCommittedResource(
            &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT),
            D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
            &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Tex2D(DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT, width, height,
                1, 0, 1, 0, D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_DEPTH_STENCIL),
            D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_DEPTH_WRITE,
            &optimizedClearValue,
            IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_DepthBuffer)
        ));

        // Update the depth-stencil view.
        D3D12_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC dsv = {};
        dsv.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
        dsv.ViewDimension = D3D12_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
        dsv.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
        dsv.Flags = D3D12_DSV_FLAG_NONE;

        device->CreateDepthStencilView(m_DepthBuffer.Get(), &dsv,
            m_DSVHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
    }
}
```

Do we have to release old Depth/Stencil views, because the in the above code they are just overwriting the descriptor in the descriptor heap with a new view (CreateDepthStencilView), but not releasing the old one? Is that a leak?

this is the github [link](https://github.com/jpvanoosten/LearningDirectX12/blob/v0.0.2/Tutorial2/src/Tutorial2.cpp#L233) to the code

(if it is in a descriptor (in a descriptor heap) vs just a stack based view, do i need to deallocate both of them, if so how?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SRV, CBV, UAV, RTV, and DSV "Views" in DirectX 12 are in memory 'owned' by the heaps they are allocated into. You can just reuse those slots if you want. The `Create*View` methods just fill out data into that memory. The memory itself is freed when the associated heap is freed.

Vertex Buffer and Index Buffer Views are just simple structures as well.

The ref-counted part you need to make sure you release are the ID3D12Resource and ID3D12Heap objects.

> In addition to that tutorial, you may want to take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started).